# Javascript stranges lag finding a key in a map

Tags: javascript

I have a real time application with a pretty simple data structure : a map going from a time (in seconds) to a state (the state of my system). And for each frame I get a given time and I want to retrieve the state for this time.

for example if I have 3 states :

- 0.3a -> state_a
- 0.7 -> state_b
- 1.1 -> state_c

if I am given t=0.5 I should return state_b because 0.7 is the minimum key such that k >= t

Now here is my implementation (in pseudo code) :

```
var states // my map [time -> state]
var t // the time
var keys = keysOf(states) // get the key set of the states
var correctKeys = filter(keys, (k) -> k >= t) // removes all keys less than t
var selectedKey = min(correctKeys) // the best key
return states[selectedKey] // return the state we want to render
```

This code works perfectly is decently fast. The problem it breaks in some cases. In fact in JavaScript keys are always strings. so when I filter them and find the minimum I am using the alphabetical order and not the number order and then we have 19 < 2

I fixed it by doing this **at program startup**:

```
keys = map(keys, parseFloat) //convert all keys to floats
```

Now everything is perfect but it is insanely slow (just by adding this line of code)

I tried to find out where it could come from and my ideas are :

- comparing floats is slower than comparing strings *which is false according to my benchmarks* (sorry I'm not able to post them as jsperf is down and their herokuapp does not seem to work)
- accessing a map using a float is slower than accessing it with a string. *According to my benchmarks it is true (17x slower on nodejs, but only 1.3x on firefox 39)*

What do you think about this problem ?

Am I missing a simple way to solve this ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally agree with @jantimon and @Cristy that a binary search is much better if you care about performance as you have O(n) complexity at all times.

I just noticed that there is a very easy solution to your problem with a minimal number of changes to your code and does not require to translate keys to floats.

```
var a = '19';
var b = '2';

console.log(b >= a); // TRUE - as it compares strings
console.log(b - a >=0); // FALSE - as it compares ints / floats
```

Comment: As far I read this is the only correct solution I found as jantimon and cristies solution works as bad as mine : console.log(data[getClosestKey(data, 504.3260)]);" returns undefined in the jantimon jsbin

Comment: I agree with all of about binary search but my arrays are quite small (less than 2000) elements. It would not make sense to make a BS. The code would be more complex and error prone while this still __looks__ laggy

Comment: I only posted this because of you last sentence. `Am I missing a simple way to solve this ?` =) Happy coding!

Comment: I just wanted to say : "using binary search does __not__ solve the problem"

Comment: feel free to accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I found out "why" it was laggy but you found "how to solve this". You deserved it. A big thank you

Comment: BTW we need to sort the keys before doing a BS. If the keys are not constant we would have O(n log(n) + log(n)) = O(n log(n)) my solution is O(n) which is better in this case

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In fact using floats as keys instead of strings is not slower it is **visibly** slower. Let me explain. At each frame I render the state of the program. It looks laggy but in fact it was not.

The problem came from :

```
parseFloat("1.00").toString() != "1.00"
```

So sometime when I want to get a state "1" in this example . It does not exist in the map (whereas "1.00" exists as a key). The application does not have anything to render and skip the frame hence it *looks* laggy.

Comment: In this case I would propose to delete the question as it won't have any value for someone who is searching for performance related issues ;)

Comment: I agree, I __thought__ it was a performance issue but I found out it was not. I will remove the tag now

Comment: and rename the question ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just do a binary search, it's O(logN) and this is a basic use case for it.

Store all the `keys` in a sorted array and then you can search for the minimum key with a value larger than `X` in `O(logN)`.

As long as you have like under 1 billion keys, it shouldn't be a performance problem (more likely to have a memory problem than a computation time one).

Comment: I know but as you can see in my question the problem is accessing the map with a string. If I do what you say I would still have selectedKey as a float and reading states[selectedKey] would be still slow. It does not solve the problem.

Comment: Exactly - you are running over all values one to two times. With binary search it should be way less

Comment: The slow thing is not going over all the values twice. Otherwise it would still be slow with string as keys

Comment: The problem is not selection from an array, that is not slow by any means.

Comment: Did you read entirely my post ? The slowdown appeared after i converted the keys from string to floats

Comment: Yes, but I do not get how you think accessing an array (with any key) is going to be your bottleneck. If you want you can store the keys in another array like so: 0->'0.3a' , `1->'0.7'` , etc... But this means you'll have to search the index of the key in this array which will be A LOT slower than simply accessing the map with the string key. How many operations do you need to support per second?

Comment: Also, can you show your benchmarks? I really think that your premise is wrong and the performance drop comes from filtering/creating the map **not from accessing an element by its key**

Comment: Then why as soon as I convert the strings to float the code is insanely slow. Please note that if I keep using strings as key the code is perfectly fine (I know BS is faster but my question is about explaining this performance drop)

Comment: Because the conversion itself is slow.

Comment: I do not do it at each frame... sorry if it was not clear but I thought it was evident (I edited the post)

Comment: You should create a benchmark where you isolate this issue. There is a lot of stuff that could actually slow your code, having nothing to do with the accessing of the elements.